# Get code output nicer in R Markdown Knit? Breaking into two parts

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown

I am knitting R Markdown (Rmd) to HTML, but some code outputs are not pretty, e.g., like the picture attached.[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao0j9.png)

How can I make output in one part if possible? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the [knitr::kable()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) functions

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.